# Are all vector spaces also tensor spaces? If not, what are some counterexamples?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, tensors

So I know there's several ways to define what a tensor is.  Probably the most common is that a tensor quantity is a quantity that's invariant under coordinate transformations.  But isn't that also the case for vector spaces in general?  All vector spaces have a basis, so I would think we should always be able to perform a change of basis on them.

Comment: A tensor is not "invariant under coordinate transformations."  Nothing is genuinely invariant under coordinate transformations except scalars. You mean that a tensor changes in a particular (multilinear) way under coordinate transformations.  Is $\mathbf R^3$ a tensor space? What would it mean to say "no"?  A tensor space is a particular kind of construction (input is one or more vector spaces, output is their tensor product space).  I think the question you pose is kind of a strange one.

Comment: what you have to do is concentrate on multilinear transformations and the sets of them that form vector space per se

Comment: For every vector space $V$, one can define $V^{\otimes k} = V\otimes \cdots \otimes V$ ($k$ times). Well, $V^{\otimes 1} = V$ is a tensor space. But really, this $k=1$ case is mostly nitpicking about conventions and terminology, there's not much content to it.

Comment: @KCd, by "invariant under coordinate transformations", I mean that all that happens is a change of basis.  That is, if T is a linear transformation from V1 to V2, and we apply a coordinate transformation to T, the output of the coordinate transformation should still map V1 to V2 in EXACTLY the same manner.  The elements of V1 and V2 will likely be REPRESENTED in terms of different basis vectors than before, but each element of  V1 should still be mapped to the EXACT same element of V2 as beforehand.

Comment: A better term to use is calling something a "coordinate-free concept" or say the concept does not depend on coordinates.